# Is it possible to serve in memory files statically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Using express, I am trying to serve a folder statically which was created using an in memory file system. As of yet this has not been working for me, and I am not sure if this is even possible. Here is what I have tried.

```
const express = require("express");
const Memory = require("memory-fs");
const mfs = new Memory();

const html = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
</body>

</html>
`;

mfs.mkdirpSync("/public");
mfs.writeFileSync("/public/index.html", html, "utf-8");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("server is running"));
```

This code just gives me `Cannot GET /`. Can this be done?

Comment: Since Its being served statically I don't need to. In other words, if the public folder existed in my folders and not just in memory this code would have been enough to see the html file.

Comment: Not with `express.static`, there is an issue, that suggests to [enable use with memory-fs](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/issues/83). But it shouldn't be to much work to copy the code of `serve-static` and `send` and modify it so that it uses an `memory-fs` instance instead of `fs`.